# Laws for daily life for when Moshiach comes?

Tags: ymoth-hamoshiach

There are laws in the Rambam that talk about Moshiach, but are there laws for laypeople that describe the expected changes in daily life?

Like prayers for example, it will probably be different as many parts of it are about requesting for Moshiach to come. Kaddish, Amidah, etc, is mostly praying for the coming of Moshiach.

How will we know what to say with our phylacteries every morning?

Comment: Probably it'll be posted on the internet?

Comment: @DoubleAA but what if you have a kosher phone?

Comment: @larry909 the minute a kosher phone makes keeping halacha more difficult rather than easier is the minute it stops being kosher.

Comment: https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_55877_85.pdf

Comment: Machlokes In the Gemara if when mashiach is here will the world be different. Halachos included. Learn Kodshim ...

Comment: Tahoros will also come in handy

Comment: I expect that around the time the Moshiach comes, we'll have a proper Sanhedrin to decide/resolve what changes, how it changes, and how to make the public aware of those changes. Hopefully we'll have it by the time he comes, speedily, and in our day.

Answer (score -2):

Even though "the (three) daily prayers were instituted in place of Korbanot," what would be a good reason for essentially changing it?  From Modeh Ani on awakening until Ani H' Eloheikhem at sleep, most of it is directed at the heart and emunah.  Didn't people stray after their hearts and eyes right in front of Moshe Rabbeinu, and also the Neviim rebuked people for perfunctory Offerings without the heart and justice.

And the majority opinion from Rambam (Hilkhot Melakhim 12) to Rabbi Nachman of Breslev and many others is in Yemot HaMashiach the natural worldly order will not change.  In particular, R' Nachman said however as per Isa. 2 people will cast away and be ashamed of their craving for [money](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Translation:Chayey_Moharan#597), and even the Maskilim will acknowledge Mashiach's supreme wisdom -- but Mashiach will have a harder time winning over those who follow some fake religious [leaders](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Translation:Kuntres_haHosafoth#23_Rabbeinu_z%22l_said_that_Mashiach_will_have_to_do_more_work_with_the_Chassidic_imposters_than...).  Thus the heart, emunah and prayer are the ultimate frontier, beyond that of politics, intellect and nature.  תָּשׁוּרִי מֵרֹאשׁ אֲמָנָה "Look from the head, Amana" (Song 4:8) -- do not read it Amana but Emunah.

And maybe we should read it
תפילות במקום קורבנות תקנום (טור, אורח חיים, צח)
The prayers -- *in* the place of Korbanot *are established/are the fix.*

Comment: What about the third to last blessing in the amida?

Comment: Aderaba -- lit'filatem she'eh.  And: hashev ha'avodah -- still, the avodah sh'b'lev must always return.  And if not: t'kabel b'ratzon -- "I have despised your sacrifices" And: techezeina -- versus re'iah -- doesn't that point to a spiritual seeing whether the physical is present or not?

Comment: I can list you dozens of prayer bits that would seem inappropriate. You know that.

Comment: Bits or parts yes, but do you envision larger parts or the essential nature changing?

Comment: The question wasn't "will the essential nature of prayer change when mashiach comes"